# Bootstrap spacing between columns in a row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am struggling adding spacing (or margin) between columns using the grid system in bootstrap. My html and css is below. I could not get any of the solutions posted online to work. The goal is spacing between col-8 and col-4. Any suggestions? Thanks!

HTML:

```
      <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                     hello
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="row" align="center">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <a href="#"><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-social-icons/67/github_circle_black-128.png" class="icon-resize" alt="github"></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-social-icons/67/linkedin_circle_black-128.png" class="icon-resize" alt="linkedin"></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <a href="#" class="icon-resize" target="_blank"><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-social-icons/67/twitter_circle_black-128.png" class="icon-resize" alt="twitter"></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
max-width: 960px;
height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Please add a row inside col-md-8.

Comment: How much space do you want? you could actually make col-md3, col-md-1, col-md-8? so there will be a grid difference

Comment: @mendax thanks for the recommendation, that worked great!

Answer (score 0):

here is what you're looking for:
[`gridGutterWidth`](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#grid-system)

It's usual to download the raw (`.scss` or `.less`) versions of bootstrap, so you can control the `css output` at build time. If you don't use any of them, you may find the `http://getbootstrap.com/customize/` comfortable.

Answer (score -2):

You could apply inline by

```
<div class="col-md-4" style="padding-left:1em">
```